# Does SelectiveScrollingGrid only freeze columns on first column?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a requirement to freeze the right-hand column in a grid when scrolling. Elsewhere, I am using the SelectiveScrollingGrid to freeze the left-hand column just fine, but when the frozen column is right-hand it no longer works.

Here is some XAML:

```
<!-- Right aligned frozen column results in clipping when scrollbar appears -->
<SelectiveScrollingGrid>
    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="0" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" />
    <DataGridRowHeader Grid.Column="1" 
         SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical">
</SelectiveScrollingGrid>
```

The above does not work (when you resize a window containing a grid the DataGridRowHeader area becomes clipped when the scrollbar appears).

The below XAML works just fine however:

```
<!-- Left aligned frozen column works! -->
<SelectiveScrollingGrid>
    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" />
    <DataGridRowHeader Grid.Column="0" 
         SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical">
</SelectiveScrollingGrid>
```

Can SelectiveScrollingGrid be used with a frozen column on the right? If not is there another solution?

Comment: Where you able to solve your Problem?

Comment: Oh gosh, don't remember. This was years ago! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

you can freeze any column you like, other columns would scroll pass/float underneath the frozen columns, in below snippet the text block in the first column is only allowed to scroll vertically ( horizontal scroll will have no effect on this text block)

```
<SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=XX,Path=ActualWidth}" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=LastName,Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Address,Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="1111111111111" Grid.Column="0" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" ></TextBlock>

                            <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="3" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>

                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
```